# Opening one child form from two parents

Tags: c#, winforms

okay, i'm trying to open one form from two different parents, and I can't figure out how to get it to work.  I tried using a boolean for AdminStartMenu and TeacherStartMenu to make one true if opening from one and one false from opening from another, but that doesn't seem to work.

How do I get one child to work for two different parents?

Thanks!

```
public partial class EditUser : Form
{
    AdminStartMenu pf;
    TeacherStartMenu tp;
    public bool first = true;
    public int st = 0;
    public bool Editting;
    public bool Adding;
    public bool Viewing;

    public bool AdminParent;
    public bool TeacherParent;

    public EditUser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public EditUser(AdminStartMenu Parent)
    {

        pf = Parent;
        InitializeComponent();
        EditFunction();
        if (pf.Adding == true)
        {
            BlankForm();
            SaveButton.Text = "Save";
        }
        if (pf.Editting == true)
        {
            FillFormVariables();
            SaveButton.Text = "Save";
        }
    }

    public EditUser(TeacherStartMenu TParent)
    {
        tp = TParent;
        InitializeComponent();
        EditFunction();
        if (tp.Adding == true)
        {
            BlankForm();
            SaveButton.Text = "Save";
        }
        if (tp.Editting == true)
        {
            FillFormVariables();
            SaveButton.Text = "Save";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use one form? Why not use two separate forms; one for each parent form. Maybe you could create a general form, and have the two child forms inherit from it, so as to save on time.

Comment: Upon further inspection, I think you'll need to give us more information. What is the problem with this code? From what I see there don't seem to be any obvious errors.

Comment: it just plainly doesn't work.  there's A LOT more code than this, this is just the part that doesn't work.  I could make a second form, but I'd rather get it all to work from this.

When I try to open edit user from the TeacherStartMenu, it doesn't work, simply.  Let me know if you need any other info

Comment: But what doesn't work? What is the expected result, and what is actually happening? Does the form not open? Is it not using the right constructor?

Comment: When I am in the TeacherStartMenu, and i click the EditUser button, Edit user does not open, and it gives me an error.
`private void EditUserButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Editting = true;
            Adding = false;
            EditUser add = new EditUser(this);
            add.MdiParent = this;
            add.Show();
        }`

that is the code in TeacherStartMenu that should open EditUser, but it doesn

Comment: "Form that was specified to be the MdiParent for this form is not an MdiContainer.
Parameter name: vale.

i use the exact same code from the AdminStartMenu and it works fine

Comment: What do your parent form's classes inherit from?

Comment: nothing, there's a login, but it's not the parent. it just closes the login and opens the respective start page

Comment: Every form inherits from something, whether it's the original `Form` class or something that inherits from it ;)

Comment: then it inherits from login then

Comment: Can you post the class definitions for the parent forms?

Comment: The error message in your comment says the parent form is not an MDI container. Is it supposed to be an MDI container? Are you trying to show the EditUser form as a modal dialog?

Comment: figured this out, sorry i hadn't been responding.  thanks for help anyways guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Hasan is right about having things coupled too much between the two, you might be able to simplify one form calling the other but putting common things regardless of the type of user.. maybe something like using an Interface to classify your StartMenus.  I see they have common elements, so i you had declared an interface, such as:

```
public interface IMyCommonParent
{
    bool Adding { get; set; }
    bool Editing { get; set; }
    bool Viewing { get; set; }
}

public class AdminStartMenu : DerivedFromSomeOtherClass, IMyCommonParent
{  // being associated with IMyCommonParent, this class MUST have a declaration
   // of the "Adding", "Editing", "Viewing" boolean elements
}

public class TeacherStartMenu : DerivedFromSomeOtherClass, IMyCommonParent
{ // same here }
```

they are both support the "IMyCommonParent" interface,  your child form could accept any object that supports that interface.  Then, you don't have to know specifically which one was used to start the child form, and can preserve it into a property of the form

```
public class ChildForm : Form
{
   private IMyCommonParent whichMenu
   private bool IsAdminMode;

   public ChildForm(IMyCommonParent UnknownParent)
   {
      whichMenu = UnknownParent;
      // then a flag to internally detect if admin mode or not based on
      // the ACTUAL class passed in specifically being the admin parent instance
      IsAdminMode = ( UnknownParent is AdminStartMenu );

      // the rest is now generic.
      InitializeComponent();
      EditFunction();

      if( whichMenu.Adding )
         BlankForm();
      else if( whichMenu.Editing )
         FillFormVariables();

      SaveButton.Text = "Save";
   }
}
```